# why cast of user code and employee id failed on post action when click submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

**I work on asp.net MVC web application . i face issue on `RequesterIndex`
action with type Post failed to cast user code to employee id  .**

action `Requester index` with type post fire when failed cast

and  it give me message Invalid File No .

Why this message display for me . I assign value for session user code

to employee id also i store employee id on hidden field to avoid reset

value after submit button click.

Why message Invalid File No display when click submit button this is my

question ?

1 - model property `EmpId` that represent employee Id

```
public class ResignationRequester 
{     
        
public int EmpID { get; set; }
}
```

2 - controller with action result for Requester Index Get when Load Data

```
http://ucuatappweb:907/Resignation/RequesterIndex?filenumber=123650

public class ResignationController : Controller
{
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RequesterIndex(string filenumber)
{
   
    int employeeFileNo;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filenumber))
    {
      
        if (int.TryParse(filenumber, out employeeFileNo))
        {
       
            Session[SessionKeys.UserCode] =  employeeFileNo;
           
             

                resignationRequester.EmpID = Convert.ToInt32(Session[SessionKeys.UserCode].ToString());
                Session[SessionKeys.UserCode] =  employeeFileNo;
        }
               
        
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.errorMsg = "unauthorized user";
    }
    return View(resignationRequester);
}
```

3 - when click submit button requester index with type post fire

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RequesterIndex(ResignationRequester resignationRequester)
{
    dynamic responseData = new ExpandoObject();
    responseData.success = false;
    responseData.message = "";
    try
    {
        var filenumber = resignationRequester.EmpID;
        if (Session[SessionKeys.UserCode] != null)
        {
            
            if (int.TryParse(Session[SessionKeys.UserCode].ToString(), out int empId))
            {
              
                resignationRequester.EmpID = empId;
            }
            else
            {
                
                responseData.success = false;
                responseData.message = "Invalid File No";
                return Json(responseData);
            }
            
           
        }
        else
        {
            responseData.success = false;
            responseData.message = "No Data For This File No";
            return Json(responseData);
        }
    }
   
    catch (System.FormatException ex)
    {
        responseData.success = false;
        responseData.message = ex.Message;
    }
    return Json(responseData);
    
}
}
```

4 - View display data `requesterIndex.cshtml`

```
<h2 style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 5px;padding-top:50px;">Resignation Form</h2>
<form id="ResignationApp" style="padding-top: 50px; border: 2px solid black;padding-left:20px;font-size:16px;">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="row">
           
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmpID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtempid", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                  
                  
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmpID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "hiddentxtempid", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                </div>
            </div>
          

        </div>
 <div class="col-md-7">
     <input id="btnsubmit" value="Submit" type="submit" style="background-color: #05014a;font-size:18px;margin-top:20px; color: #fff; height: 40px; width: 200px;margin-bottom:40px;" />
 </div>
</form>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var value = $("#txtempid").val();
     $("#hiddentxtempid").val(value);
        $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
     
            var empidval = $("#txtempid").val();
            var formData = $("#ResignationApp").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '@Url.Action("RequesterIndex", "Resignation")',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (response) {  
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    }
                   
                });
                
        });
        $("#ResignationApp").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
});
</script>
```

**Updated Post**

on POST action function, How I use the value from the hidden field ?
can you clarify that by code please

How to rely on hidden field on jQuery and action AND view requester index and action result by code answer

I use jQuery to prevent post back to server and not change URL after insert data on submit button
and i can't rid from

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmpID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtempid", @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

because this is need bossiness requirment

and when click submit button jQuery call action result post to make submit and insert data

if i remove read only editorfor above and leave hidden field

can you show me please how to assig  hidden field to employee id

Comment: In your POST, why not just use the value from the hidden field? Rather than relying on the session object.

Comment: so how to use value from hidden field on post can you show me please

Comment: I updated my original post can you check

Comment: I see you have two HTML controls that are bound to model.EmpID - is ResignationRequester your view model? If so, you should just be able to get the value from the view model.

Comment: Why is JQuery needed to post the form? Why not just rely on the form post? please update your question to provide clarity on this detail

Comment: But you're not doing anything with empId...you just check that it's there on the form, when it's readonly on the form anyway. What's the post in posting that to the server?

Comment: what you mean by that

Comment: This is a waste of my time.

Comment: i post employee id

Comment: yes i post employee id and use requesterindex post action when click submit button

Comment: ok i accept remove read-only editor for emp id so how to pass hidden field instead of session please